# Make Redis server secure on Digital Ocean

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, redis, docker-compose, digital-ocean

I am using [redis container](https://hub.docker.com/_/redis/) for my Ruby on Rails application. My application is deployed on Digital Ocean server. I got an email that my Redis configuration is insecure, as the Redis server command is running on `redis-server *:6379` instead of `127.0.0.1:6379` which makes my Redis server insecure.

How can I configure my droplet for Redis to make it run on  `127.0.0.1:6379`?

Following are my configurations of `docker-compose.yml` for `redis`:

```
app:
  build: .
  env_file: .env.production
  environment:
    RAILS_ENV: production
    REDIS_URL: redis://redis:6379/0
  links:
    - db
    - redis
  expose:
    - "3000"
  volumes:
    - .:/usr/src/app
db:
  image: postgres:9.4.5
  volumes:
     - project-postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
web:
  build: .
  dockerfile: config/containers/Dockerfile-nginx
  links:
    - app
    - redis
  environment:
    REDIS_URL: redis://redis:6379/0

  # expose the port we configured Nginx to bind to
  ports:
    - "80:80"
elasticsearch:
  #elasticsearch image
  image: elasticsearch
  container_name: elasticsearch
  # expose the port both ports
  ports:
    - '9200:9200'
    - '9300:9300'
  volumes:
     - /data/elasticsearch:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
  environment:
    ES_JAVA_OPTS: -Xms256m -Xmx256m

redis:
  image: redis:latest
  command: redis-server

  ports:
    - '6379:6379'
  volumes:
    - 'redis:/var/lib/redis/data'

sidekiq:
  build: .
  command: bundle exec sidekiq
  links:
    - db
    - redis
  volumes:
    - .:/app
  env_file:
    - .env
```

Comment: Is that your entire compose file, including your volume definitions, compose version, and other services being run? Are there applications outside of docker that need access to your redis instance?

Comment: @BMitch I have added my complete `docker-compse.yml` file. Please see updates

Comment: A short-term solution is to set up an inbound firewall in Digital Ocean that only allows the necessary traffic. If you don't want to allow inbound traffic on port 6379, block it.

Answer (score 2):

```
    app:
      build: .
      env_file: .env.production
      environment:
        RAILS_ENV: production
        REDIS_URL: redis://redis:6379/0
      links:
        - db
        - redis
      expose:
        - "3000"
      volumes:
        - .:/usr/src/app
    db:
      image: postgres:9.4.5
      volumes:
        - project-postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    web:
      build: .
      dockerfile: config/containers/Dockerfile-nginx
      links:
        - app
        - redis
      environment:
        REDIS_URL: redis://redis:6379/0

      # expose the port we configured Nginx to bind to
      ports:
        - "80:80"
    elasticsearch:
      #elasticsearch image
      image: elasticsearch
      container_name: elasticsearch
      # expose the port both ports
      # I don't know why you want to expose this to the world.
      # I also think you should take away the ports here and link
      # the container which you want to interact with Elasticsearch 

      volumes:
        - /data/elasticsearch:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
      environment:
        ES_JAVA_OPTS: -Xms256m -Xmx256m

      # Lets say you have a Kibana container that talks to Elasticsearch then you would link them this way:
      kibana:
      image: kibana:6.2.3
      links:
        - elasticsearch
      environment:
        ES_URL: http://elasticsearch:9200 
      # If you want people to connect to kibana directly then you can go ahead and open ports.
      # In an ideal world you will put both ES and Kibana behind Nginx as reverse proxy with some authentication on such as HTTP auth or even LDAP auth.
      ports:
        - "5601:5601"


      redis:
        image: docker.io/redis:3.0

      # You don't need to open ports here to the world.
      # As long as the containers that need to communicate with the redis container are linked using "links"
      # keyword, then the containers would be able to talk to each other using their hostname. redis will use the hostname:'redis'  



    sidekiq:
      build: .
      command: bundle exec sidekiq
      links:
        - db
        - redis
      volumes:
        - .:/app
      env_file:
        - .env
```

So this won't allow you to run redis on localhost because remember that the containers have an internal network that they use to communicate with each other on. They use hostnames to reference a service or container that they interact with. So for example with this compose file redis will be available at redis:6379. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, it won't effect if we remove the ports under redis configuration. But still the redis is running as "*:6379" instead of "127.0.0.1:6379"

Comment: You can't make something listen on localhost in a docker container. Because localhost in the docker container is only accessible from within the container itself.

Comment: @umairmunir: you may need to stop your existing services before trying this out. It does look correct - see the comments that OpenBSDNinja has put in the `redis` section of the DC config.

Comment: @umairmunir is correct. You can shut down existing services with: `$ docker-compose down` this should work.

Comment: @halfer I have used the same configuration as proposed by @OpenBSNinja but still the redis is running on `*:6379` port

Comment: @OpenBSDNinja I have used `$ docker-compose down` command to down and then `$ docker-compose up`  but still redis configuration didn't changed

Comment: @umairmunir: you'll need to check `docker ps` to see what is running (and what ports are bound). The configuration here will not, as far as I can tell, give you the behaviour you are describing.